# Assignment problem with different size of sets

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, optimization, discrete-optimization

Let $A$ and $B$ be two sets with $|A| \ge |B|$, and let $f: C \to \mathbb{R}$ be a nonnegative function with $C \subseteq A×B$. Furthermore, let $D \subseteq C$ be a matching in $C$ such that $D$ provides all the elements of $B$ (through their ordered pairs). How to get

$$D^{*}=\underset{D \subseteq C}{\mathrm{argmin}} \sum_{d \in D}f(d)?$$

Similar question has been raised in [A variant of assignment problem (different sizes of sets)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255476/a-variant-of-assignment-problem-different-sizes-of-sets), but the unequal size problem has not been asnwered.

Comment: As I read it, it _was_ answered. Where in the answer to the linked problem do you see the assumption of equal sizes?

Comment: $\sum_{b}x_{a,b}=|B|$ is a real constraint? It should be replaced by $\sum_{b}x_{a,b}=1$ and $\sum_{a}x_{a,b} \le 1$ for all $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, where $x_{a,b} \in \{0,1\}$.

Comment: Right, the posted answer to the linked question is flawed -- your objections are correct. You should post a comment to that answer, raising those objections. But if the posted answer is modified in the way you've suggested, wouldn't it then be correct, and hence, answer your question?

Comment: Note that in comparison to the linked question, you've switched the roles of $A,B$, which is somewhat confusing.

Comment: Also, can you post a numerical example (or a link to one) for testing?

Comment: By the way, the definitions of $A$ and $B$ are not interchanged. Let $$A =\{ 1.15, 1.18, 1.22, 1.28, 1.305, 1.32, 1.8, 1.91, 2.12 \}$$ and $$B = \{1.1, 1.3, 1.31, 1.5, 1.7, 1.9, 2.1 \}.$$ Furthermore, let $$f(a,b)=|a-b|$$ for all $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. I would like to match all the elements of $B$ with minimal sum-distance.

Comment: Right, I misread it -- the roles of $A,B$ are the same in both problems. Thanks for the example.

Comment: Using the integer linear programming strategy outlined in Hans Engler's answer to the linked question, I ran your example using the integer option of Maple's LPSolve command. It completed in less than a second, and returned a valid matching with a minimum cost of 0.385.

Comment: I posted your objection to Hans Engler's answer in the linked question as a comment. Let's see what he says.